# Mongoid skip validation or set default value for document with nil embeds_many

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, activemodel

Mongoid won't save document with no reference to `embeds_many` field, and I can't find any mention in documentation on how to make `embeds_many` default to `[]` if not present, or alternatively to skip that validation if not present.

Here's a simple reproduction

```
class ModelOne
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String
  embeds_many :model_twos
end
```

```
class ModelTwo
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :model_one
end
```

```
  mOne = ModelOne.new({name: "foo"})
  if mOne.save
   ...
  else
    pp mOne.errors.full_messages
  end
```

Which results in an error like;

`["ModelTwos is invalid"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"...by default, Mongoid will validate the children of any relation that are loaded into memory via a `validates_associated`... If you do not want this behavior, you may turn it off when defining the relation." ([documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/6.4/tutorials/mongoid-relations/#validations))

So, the following should help hopefully:

```
embeds_many :model_twos, validate: false
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I was hoping to find, but you answered the question, so thanks!